# How to expand Powershell variable referenced in Get-Job "Command"

Tags: powershell

I've re-written this to provide a simple, generic example.

When running a loop I can create a number of jobs using a variable, thus:

```
foreach ( $n in 1..10 ) {
    start-job { echo $n }
}
```

This creates a list of jobs as follows:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
13     Job13           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
15     Job15           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
17     Job17           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
19     Job19           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             echo $n
```

How can I tell the value of the variable used in Job1?  The variable is listed in the *Command*, but it is **not expanded**:

```
PS C:\Users\James> ( get-job 1) | fl *


State         : Running
HasMoreData   : True
StatusMessage :
Location      : localhost
Command       :  echo $n
JobStateInfo  : Running
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : d000978d-9188-4c96-8563-db068c7dc31b
Id            : 1
Name          : Job1
ChildJobs     : {Job2}
PSBeginTime   : 11/06/2017 21:43:31
PSEndTime     :
PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
Output        : {}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
Information   : {}
```

Nor is the *Command* expanded in the ChildJob:

```
PS C:\Users\James> (get-job 2) |fl *


State         : Completed
StatusMessage :
HasMoreData   : True
Location      : localhost
Runspace      : System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace
Debugger      : System.Management.Automation.RemotingJobDebugger
IsAsync       : True
Command       :  echo $n
JobStateInfo  : Completed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : 39bb0735-eecf-4d61-afa2-3db9d14097a4
Id            : 2
Name          : Job2
ChildJobs     : {}
PSBeginTime   : 11/06/2017 21:43:58
PSEndTime     : 11/06/2017 21:44:03
PSJobTypeName :
Output        : {$null}
Error         : {}
Progress      : {parent = -1 id = 0 act = Preparing modules for first use. stat =   cur =  pct = -1 sec = -1 type =
                Completed}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
Information   : {}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can obtain the expanded variables from these jobs?

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Original Scenario:

I have executed a command within a loop to remove snapshots from a bunch of VMs:

```
get-vm | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -match "TRU-JDF-CMTEST[1-5]"} | ForEach-Object { Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $_.Name | Remove-VMSnapshot -AsJob }
```

This creates jobs, as the example below:

```
(Get-Job 4)|fl *


State         : Failed
StatusMessage :
HasMoreData   : True
Location      :
Command       : get-vm | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -match "TRU-JDF-CMTEST[1-5]" } | ForEach-Object {
                Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $_.Name | Remove-VMSnapshot -AsJob }
JobStateInfo  : Failed
Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
InstanceId    : b357f708-59cf-40f1-a07e-a86ddc45985a
Id            : 4
Name          : Job4
ChildJobs     : {}
PSBeginTime   : 04/05/2017 10:33:39
PSEndTime     : 04/05/2017 10:33:39
PSJobTypeName :
Output        : {}
Error         : {Object reference not set to an instance of an object.}
Progress      : {parent = -1 id = 0 act = Virtual Machine Operation stat = Exception cur =  pct = 100 sec = -1 type =
                Completed}
Verbose       : {}
Debug         : {}
Warning       : {}
```

In this example, the meat of the command is listed as:

```
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $_.Name | Remove-VMSnapshot -AsJob
```

How can I ascertain the value of `$_.Name` in this iteration?

Comment: Did you verify the first part to see whenever you actually get some VMs? Otherwise just check the contents of `$_` or `$_.Name`?

Comment: The loop itself works as expected.  My question is: how do I "...just check the contents of $_ of $_.Name" when the command was created within a job?

Comment: You don't. The `-AsJob` is an argument to `Remove-VMSnapshot`. But as you're within a script block anyway you can just check it before supplying it to `Get-VMSnapshot` and in turn `Remove-VMSnapshot`.

Comment: I think I follow you, Seth. Does that mean that the job will contain a reference or GUID of the snapshot that was piped to it? If so how would I get it? If not, I guess the best approach would be to avoid the use of the - AsJob argument, and instead explicitly create a Remove-VM job named with the value of $_.Name for identification purposes.

Comment: Did you evaluate the values of `$_.Name` before passing them to the cmdlets? Currently you do no checking of them what so ever. If you do have issues you should verify the validity of those components. In addition it seems to be a test setup so just give it a shot with out the `-AsJob`. If that works without a problem you could think about why it breaks if you do use it.

Comment: The variable contains valid data.

Comment: This question still stands as I have not receive a satisfactory explanation as to how to establish the true value of the variable that was used in the job.  // (As an aside, to successfully remove all snapshots in the example, I simply sorted the found snapshots by creation date and deleted them in descending order.)

Comment: Did you try to run it with `-Debug` or `-Verbose` to get more information? Did you try to further investigate by using [`Get-Job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-job) (e.g. Example 9)?

Comment: Thanks Seth, that example revealed a child job, but without any expansion of variables.  I've updated the question to a simpler example to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to expand the variable passed to the background job; you just need to store it in an array or hashtable for subsequent reference.

I played around with your simplified example and discovered that local variables may not expand at all in a `Start-Job` script block - unless the `Using` modifier is utilized (see `Get-Help about_Remote_Variables` - even for jobs which will execute on the local computer).  To illustrate, the following example creates four background jobs without `Using` and four more with `Using`.

```
$JobArray = @()

foreach ( $n in 1..4 ) {
    $JobName = $n.ToString()
    Write-Host ("Starting job " + $JobName + "...")
    $JobArray += Start-Job -Name $JobName -ScriptBlock { Write-Host ("Background job " + $JobName) }
}

foreach ( $n in 5..8 ) {
    $JobName = $n.ToString()
    Write-Host ("Starting job " + $JobName + "...")
    $JobArray += Start-Job -Name $JobName -ScriptBlock { Write-Host ("Background job " + $Using:JobName) }
}

Write-Host ("`nWaiting for all jobs to complete...")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$InProgress = $false
do {
    $InProgress = $false
    foreach ( $Job in $JobArray ) {
        if ($Job.JobStateInfo.State -eq "Running") {
            $InProgress = $true
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
    }
} while ($InProgress -eq $true)

foreach ( $Job in $JobArray ) {
    Write-Host ("`nJob Name: " + $Job.Name + "  Job ID: " + $Job.ID + "  State: " + $Job.JobStateInfo.state + "  Results on next line...")
    Receive-Job -Job $Job -Keep
}

Write-Host ("`nComplete.  To remove expired jobs run:`n   Remove-Job -State Completed")
```

The example, above, stores each job in an array, so Job #4 can be accessed as $JobArray[4].  Also, each job is named according to the job number (the `foreach` iterator counter `$n`, not the job ID assigned by PowerShell which can vary).  This allows access to a specific job by the number/name you have assigned it.

A similar approach may be applicable to your VM snapshot scenario.  The following is UNTESTED and should not be attempted in production until verified in a testing environment:

```
$VmArray = @(get-vm | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -match "TRU-JDF-CMTEST[1-5]"})
ForEach ($vm in $VmArray) {
    $vmname = $vm.Name
    $snapshot = Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $vmname
    $snapshotname = $snapshot.Name
    Start-Job -Name ($vmname + "-" + $snapshotname) -ScriptBlock { Remove-VMSnapshot -VM $Using:vmname -Name $Using:snapshotname }
}
```

By breaking things out into multi-line code blocks, you have more opportunity to assign intermediate local variables.  I did not preserve the job returned by `Start-Job` in an array, as I did in my first example, but you could do that if you wish.  You might also be able to store each job in a hashtable, rather than in an array.  In the hashtable, the key could be the job name you have assigned, and the value could be the job object itself.

Comment: I'll accept _"You do not need to expand the variable passed to the background job; you just need to store it in an array or hashtable for subsequent reference."_ as the answer.  A little life experience has taught me the importance of error-checking, and I now strongly advocate the use of try-catch-finally when dealing with variables.  Thanks for the tip on $Using Remote Variables, this looks a lot easier than pushing parameters.